Lenovo docks not recognized in initramfs after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04
Since upgrading my Ubuntu installation from 23.10 to 24.04, my Lenovo docks (Thunderbolt 4 dock and Hybrid USB-C dock) are not recognized in the initramfs. This issue occurs when I need to enter my hardware encryption password during boot. As a result:

Displays connected to the docks show nothing.
The keyboard connected via USB to the dock is not usable to enter my password.

However, once the system boots into the full OS, everything works as expected. This is particularly inconvenient as I have to open my Lenovo P14s Gen 4 (with AMD Ryzen 7) laptop just to enter the password.
What steps can I take to ensure that my docks are recognized during the initramfs stage so that I can use my external displays and keyboard to enter my encryption password?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I suggest you contact the dock maker and find out if they have any kind of update you need to do with the dock. It may and certainly sounds like it just is not ready for the new OS.

As I said, after entering the encryption password, everything works. I seems like some module is missing in the initramfs but I don't know how to find out.
